# Assign MySQL database value to a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get the password of a specified username, assign it to a PHP variable, and then print it. Here's the code for it -

```
$user = $_POST["uname"];
$pass = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");                                              
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($pass);

$specific = $result['pass'];

echo $specific;
```

The problem is that nothing is being printed at all! Even no error. What do I do?

Comment: You aren't checking for errors though.. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php You also should use prepared statements, this is open to SQL injections. Also hopefully the passwords are hashed..

Comment: $result =mysqli_fetch_array($pass,MYSQLI_ASSOC); use this. this is to fetch the db value into array format.

Comment: I am just testing the code, this isn't gonna be used anywhere. Just checking the basics.

Comment: You should test with what you are going to use.

Comment: I found my mistake! Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pass = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE username = '$user'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

This will Show you the Correct Error in your query

Answer (score 1):

Escape your values and check for errors:

```
$user = mysqli_escape_string( $con, $_POST["uname"] );
$pass = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");

# Error checking
if( $pass === false ) {
    echo 'Error: ', mysqli_error( $con );
}

# Check for no user with that password
if( mysqli_num_rows( $pass ) == 0 ) {
    echo 'No user with that username.';
}

# Use as associate arary              
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pass);

$specific = $result['pass'];

echo $specific;
```

edit: Added check for no results.